# exception on comparing a value to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am checking for session in the constructor of my controller class and getting error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on

```
if (Session["MemberId"] == null)
{
  //....Redirect to login page
}
```

Why this error is possible?. What else I can do? Is there anything per-requisite to this? like in php we need `session_start()` before checking a session value ?

Comment: Because `Session` is `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Session` is indeed null during the **construction** of your Controller. Try this instead:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["MemberId"] == null)
    {
        //....Redirect to login page
    }

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.. could you please guide where to write this function?

Comment: In your Controller class. you're simply overriding the `Initialize` method that is defined in `ControllerBase`.